# Selecting rows in dc.datatables.js

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to allow selection of a row in a datatable:

```
nasdaqTable /* dc.dataTable('.dc-data-table', 'chartGroup') */
            .dimension(dateDimension)
            // Data table does not use crossfilter group but rather a closure
            // as a grouping function
            .group(function (d) {
                var format = d3.format('02d');
                return d.dd.getFullYear() + '/' + format((d.dd.getMonth() + 1));
            })
            // (_optional_) max number of records to be shown, `default = 25`
            .size(10)
            // There are several ways to specify the columns; see the data-table documentation.
            // This code demonstrates generating the column header automatically based on the columns.
            .columns([
                // Use the `d.date` field; capitalized automatically; specify sorting order
                {
                    label: 'date',
                    type: 'date',
                    format: function(d) {
                        return d.date;
                    }
                },
                // Use `d.open`, `d.close`; default sorting order is numeric
                'open',
                'close',
                {
                    // Specify a custom format for column 'Change' by using a label with a function.
                    label: 'Change',
                    format: function (d) {
                        return numberFormat(d.close - d.open);
                    }
                },
                // Use `d.volume`
                'volume'
            ])

            // (_optional_) sort using the given field, `default = function(d){return d;}`
            .sortBy(function (d) {
                return d.dd;
            })
            // (_optional_) sort order, `default = d3.ascending`
            .order(d3.ascending)
            // (_optional_) custom renderlet to post-process chart using [D3](http://d3js.org)
            .on('renderlet', function (table) {
                table.selectAll('.dc-table-group').classed('info', true);
            });
```

This is the standard example drawn from https://github.com/dc-js/dc.datatables.js which integrates `dc.js` with `datatables.js`

However, I looked around for examples of implementation of rows being clickable and couldn't find any.

The goal I am trying to achieve is allow users to click the rows they would be interested in after playing around with the crossfilter dimensions and submitting them to a backend server.

Comment: Hi, what will you do with the rows when they are clicked? Please search for any examples of doing this with datatables.js since that is a huge community and mature library while dc.datatables.js is pretty new. Then please give a shot at integrating those examples, as I am sure they exist. I don't have time to look into this right now but I'll check back soon.

Comment: My point, in case it wasn't clear, is that dc.datatables.js is just a minuscule shim on top of the gigantic universe which is datatables.js - so if you find out how to do it with raw datatables.js it will be trivial to figure out how to poke it through the dc.datatables.js layer.

Comment: Ah noted. Thanks!